# Realm on iOS: crash while creating nested object with primaryKey

Tags: ios, swift, realm, primary-key

Can't create nested object with `primaryKey`: I have `Media` object with nested `Location` object and `Comment` object. In all these objects I've already implemented `primaryKey` and while I'm trying to create `Media` object, I get crash:

`realm.add(media, update: true)`

`Can't create object with existing primary key value ...`

By the way, the problem is with `Comment` object, but `Location` is ok, however, they are implemented similarly.

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful if you could post your model

Comment: Picture with models code added

Comment: Are you trying to add comments before you save the Media object to the realm db? If so, in memory you will have two objects with the same primaryKey which isn't allowed.

Comment: No, as I said, the only place in which I perform saving is realm.add(media, update: true) and Location with Comment are nested.

Comment: Yes, you're right :-) I was trying to add Media with all nested objects before adding it in Realm

Comment: Glad you got is resolved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the reason and it's in the wrong functions order. The right order is add Media to Realm and only then assign it to User:

```
realm.add(media, update: true)
currentUser.media.append(media)
```